# How to trigger off callback after updating state in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In React, state is not be updated instantly, so we can use callback in `setState(state, callback)`. But how to do it in Redux?

After calling the `this.props.dispatch(updateState(key, value))`, I need to do something with the updated state immediately.

Is there any way I can call a callback with the latest state like what I do in React?

Comment: Do you use `thunk`?

Comment: I think `dispatch()` is a synchronous activity. The updated state should be available in the next line.

Comment: @PraneshRavi I thought so. But I got the old state. I didn't use `thunk`.

Comment: what's your use case? You mentioned API call?

Comment: [Redux dispatch is synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43276291/2544629) .

Comment: Yes dispatch is synchronous, but subsequent update of the component's props is not. Therefore the redux state is updated in the next line, but the component's props aren't yet.

Comment: i think redux saga is a good solution, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63429981/1554340)

Comment: Use "useEffect" from the Hooks API, a more reactive way to handle this.

Answer (score 140):

**component should be updated to receive new props.**

there are ways to achieve your goal:

**1. componentDidUpdate** check if value is changed, then do something..

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
     if(prevProps.value !== this.props.value){ alert(prevProps.value) }
  }
```

**2. redux-promise** ( middleware will dispatch the resolved value of the promise)

```
export const updateState = (key, value)=>
Promise.resolve({
  type:'UPDATE_STATE',
  key, value
})
```

then in component

```
this.props.dispatch(updateState(key, value)).then(()=>{
   alert(this.props.value)
})
```

**2. redux-thunk**

```
export const updateState = (key, value) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: 'UPDATE_STATE',
    key,
    value,
  });
  return Promise.resolve();
};
```

then in component

```
this.props.dispatch(updateState(key, value)).then(()=>{
   alert(this.props.value)
})
```

Comment: In your `redux-thunk` example, you use `dispatch` as if it is synchronous. Is that the case?

Comment: @DannyHarding `dispatch` isn't synchronous. Without the `Promise.resolve()`, `this.props.value` would still return the old value. Some kind of async deferral is still needed (referencing from within a `setTimeout` would also work for example).

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk I'm wondering because the updateState function in the redux-thunk example has dispatch(someAction) immediately followed by return Promise.resolve(). The promise resolves immediately, which I imagine would create a race condition between the redux store update and the .then called in the component. Because dispatch doesn't return a promise or accept a callback, I don't think this is an accurate way to know when the redux store has been updated. I think that the answer by just-boris is correct in this case

Comment: @DannyHarding Yeah I'd agree that this method is likely not a sure fire guarantee, just illustrating that the dispatch is not synchronous.

Comment: I'm trying to use the redux-thunk solution here, but I only get `TypeError: _this.props.dispatch is not a function`?

Comment: @Krillko I think you are not using arrow functions. If so this modified code should work `export function updateSomeData(data) {
  // return { type: types.LOAD_SOME_DATA, data };
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: types.LOAD_SOME_DATA,
      data
    });
    return Promise.resolve();
  };
}`

Comment: `dipatch` returns a promise. You can chain off that.

Answer (score 40):

With Hooks API:

`useEffect` with the prop as input.

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export default function ValueComponent() {
   const value = useSelector(store => store.pathTo.value)

   useEffect(() => {
     console.log('New value', value) 
     return () => {
        console.log('Prev value', value) 
     }

   }, [value])

   return <div> {value} </div>
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer was written before React Hooks. This should be the accepted answer now after the introduction of hooks. It's a more Reactive way to handle changes.

Comment: No necessarily. What if You want to trigger a function with updated store data on button click BUT, you dont want to trigger that function everytime that particular data has changed?

Comment: agreed with @mkatanski, use effect trigger everytime, it's not natural to handle that way

Comment: @mkatanski to trigger a function with updated store data on button-click, you would just use the selector value in your click handler. Based on op's question performing some action when state changes falls into the category of a side-effect which `useEffect` is intended for.

Comment: THIS IS THE BEST ANSWERS, PLEASE IF YOU SCROW DOWN HERE, KNOW THAT THIS ONE SHOULD BE THE CORRECT ONE SO UPVOTE IT.

Answer (score 17):

The most important point about React is one-way data flow. In your example that means, that dispatching an action and state change handling should be decoupled.

You shouldn't think like "I did `A`, now `X` becomes `Y` and I handle it", but "What do I do when `X` becomes `Y`", without any relation to `A`. Store state can be updated from mutiple sources, in addition to your component, Time Travel also can change state and it will not be passed through your `A` dispatch point.

Basically that means that you should use `componentWillReceiveProps` as it was proposed by @Utro

Comment: This is the answer op is really looking for (although it looks like he is not aware of this..)

Comment: I agree but this seems to be considered an antipattern: https://hackernoon.com/evil-things-you-do-with-redux-dispatch-in-updating-lifecycle-methods-ad116de882d4

Comment: what do we do now that `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated? `static getDerivedStateFromProps()` doesn't seem a suitable replacement as it can't call a callback, as far as I can tell

Answer (score 6):

You could use `subscribe` listener and it will be called when an action is dispatched. Inside the listener you will get the latest store data.

http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribelistener

Comment: `subscribe` only fires when an action is dispatched. There's no way `subscribe` would let you know if your API call has returned any data.. i think! :D

Comment: You could dispatch another action when your request completes (successfully or unsuccessfully).

Comment: I am not convinced that any of the other solutions proposed here actually work, because I don't see a way for a promise to resolve or a callback to fire after the state is updated. This method gets called for every store update, not just the one that happens after your event, but that shouldn't be too hard to work around. In particular, the link [write a custom observeStore utility](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/303#issuecomment-125184409) from the page you linked to is very helpful.

Comment: Link Page Not Found

Comment: this is preferred while using function based components..

Answer (score 3):

You can use a thunk with a callback

```
myThunk = cb => dispatch =>
  myAsyncOp(...)
    .then(res => dispatch(res))
    .then(() => cb()) // Do whatever you want here.
    .catch(err => handleError(err))
```

Comment: Perfect for what I was needing!

Answer (score 2):

As a simple solution you can use:
[redux-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-promise)

But if you using **redux-thunk**, you should do sth like this:

```
function addCost(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      dispatch(something);
     });
    return promise1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`redux`'s `dispatch` returns a promise that you can chain off from like so.

```
     const submissionPromise: any = dispatch(submitFundRequest())
        submissionPromise
            .then((response: any) => {
                if(response.error) {
                    return console.log('There was an error', response)
                }
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Submission',
                    text: 'You have successfully submitted the requisition'
                })
            })
            .catch((err: any) => {
                console.log('Submission failed', err)
            })
```

`response.error` is only set if the thunk was rejected. In your `submitFundRequest` thunk, you can do something like this to reject.

```
export const submitFundRequest = createAsyncThunk(
    'fundRequest/submitFundRequest',
    async function submit(payload, thunkAPI) {
        try {
            ...
        } catch(e: any) {
            const error = { message: e.response.statusMessage }
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error)
        }
    }
)
```