# Is store.dispatch in Redux synchronous or asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, single-page-application

I realize this is a basic question but I had no luck finding the answer elsewhere.

Is `store.dispatch` synchronous or asynchronous in `Redux` ?

In case it is asynchronous is there a possibility to add a callback after the action has been propagated as it is possible with `React` ?

Comment: Notice that the state is updated synchronous (`getState()`) but `mapStateToProps` doesn't. So `this.props.value` is the old value while `getState().value` is the new one - https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-forked-0m5eo?file=/Page.js

Comment: in the new v7 implementation, dispatch remains synchronous, but if you are using it with react, then the component updates are batched, similar to react setState

Answer (score 121, accepted):

AFAIK, dispatching action is synchronous. In case if you are willing to address the asynchronous call, you can use the [thunk-middleware](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) in redux, where dispatch is provided as a callback function which you can invoke as per your convenience. For more info, checkout this answer on SO by Author itself: [How to dispatch a Redux action with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559)

Comment: But many people suggest me: Don't call dispatch in async flow which make redux state becomes unpredictable, you should *sync* to call dispatch. But thunk-middleware just call dispatch after await, that's async flow. Which opinion is correct? sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: I am not sure about the challenges you are facing, but the overall idea of using `thunk` action is to facilitate the async flow of the code. e.g. user can dispatch the action once promise is fulfilled.

Answer (score 93):

Nobody knows better than the [code itself](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/fe0ace21910bc596cd8f3ec8ccc78bccdae7d426/src/createStore.js#L158-L216). =) As you can see `dispatch` is absolutely synchronous. The only warning here is that store `enhancers` can (and do) substitute `dispatch` method. For example, take a look [at `applyMiddleware` enhancer](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.ts#L19), it lets you jack middlewares in by replacing default `dispatch` method with its own implementation. Though I never saw any Redux `enhancer` which would actually remove synchronous nature of `dispatch`.

Comment: You should update the apply middleware link to [https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.ts#L19](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.ts#L19) (due to the redux migration from js -> ts, I can't make the edit since it's < 6 characters). Or, perhaps you should reference a commit when they still used js like in your `code itself` link, which would deadlinks due to the 'permalink' aspect of commits.