# Is it a bad idea to call a function mapped to a property and use that function's output immediately when using react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a question about the following example code, which seems to have something to do with redux data flow inside.

```
// action.js
export function doSomething() {
    return {
       type : 'FOO',
       data : 'BAR'
    };
}

// reducer.js
...
case types.FOO :
    return update(state, { mystatus : { $set : action.data } });
...

// container.js

class MyTestClass {

    ...

    handleButtonClick() {
        this.props.doSomething(); // doSomething is just simple, synchronous action creator. In this function, state.foo 
        console.log(this.props.status);  // expected output should be 'BAR' but, actual output is 'undefined'
    }

    ...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state => {
    return {
        status : state.mystatus
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        doSomething : () => {
            return dispatch(doSomthing());
        }
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyTestClass);
```

Now, this is my question.

If you see the code 'this.props.doSomething(); console.log(this.props.status);' in handleButtonClick method, the output of this code is supposed to be 'BAR'. However, I got 'undefined'.

```
this.props.doSomething();
console.log(this.props.status); // output is 'undefined'
```

And, If I change that part like following, I could get what I expected.

```
this.props.doSomething();
setTimeout(() => { console.log(this.props.status); }, 0); // now output is 'BAR'!!
```

I thought that "calling this.props.doSomething() => creating action => dispatching => mapping the changed state to the property by redux" was a series of synchronous control flow, but it does not seem to be.

There seems to be an asynchronous control flow in the process of being dispatched.

Is it a bad idea to call a function mapped to a property and use that function's output immediately when using react-redux? Could you explain how react-redux handle this inside?

Thnak you.

Comment: According to this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276291/is-store-dispatch-in-redux-synchronous-or-asynchronous, dispatch is synchronous. Where is your store creation code? We have to look at your reducer definition. Are you sure `state.mystatus` points to the correct place?

Comment: To answer your question, it is not a bad idea. I do that very often. The only difference is I use redux-thunk to define asynchronous action creators. That way, I can do `this.props.doSomething().then(() => { doSomethingElse(); })`

Comment: @nbkhope yes. I also use in that way(with usually promise). I just wanted to do some experiment to figure out how redux works internally. The store creation part should be fine. That's why console.log(this.props.status); code doesn't work, but setTimeout(...) code still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/DataFlow.html), `React Redux` uses `setState` under the hood.

> If you use bindings like React Redux, this is the point at which component.setState(newState) is called.

According to [this](https://shripadk.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html), `setState()` is asynchronous and batched for performance gains.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

[Also](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html),

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

So if you want to react to state changing in terms of view, you should use `render`hook for it. If you want to react to dispatching some action in terms of  actions (logging, initiating another action), you should create [middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) (generic cases) or use [`redux-saga`](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga)/[`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) (receiving actual particular event and do something) depending on your task type.

Comment: Thnak you! Your answer was really helpful!

Comment: @novice please consider accepting answer if it is helpful

Comment: So, now I understood that I need to make sure waiting after the rendering is triggered when reading the changed state after some action. Also, I just found that the marker to accept your answer.. This is bad ux though..