# JavaScript race condition without async code?

Tags: javascript

I seem to be encountering a race condition with a function of mine even though I am not using async functions in it

```
window.focusElem = (elem, overrideGroupNextFocus) => {
  if (!elem) return
  console.log(`FOCUS: ${elem.id}`)

  if (store.getState().app.isExitVisible &&
    elem.id !== 'exitExitButton' &&
    elem.id !== 'exitBackButton'
  ) {
    return
  }

  // Remove focus class from existing focused elements
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.focus')).forEach(e => {
    console.log(`FOCUS: ${elem.id} removing focus from ${e.id}`)
    e.classList.remove('focus')
  })

  const parentFocusGroup = findParentFocusGroup(elem)
  let elemToFocus = elem
  const focusGroupNextFocusId = parentFocusGroup ? parentFocusGroup.getAttribute('data-focusgroup-next-focus') : ''
  if (!overrideGroupNextFocus &&
    focusGroupNextFocusId &&
    document.activeElement.id !== focusGroupNextFocusId) {
    elemToFocus = parentFocusGroup.querySelector(`#${focusGroupNextFocusId}`) || elem
  }

  store.dispatch(setFocusElem(elemToFocus.id))
  if (elemToFocus.id.startsWith('appNav')) {
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.active')).forEach(e => e.classList.remove('active'))
    elemToFocus.classList.add('active')
    document.querySelector('.app-wrapper').setAttribute('data-sidebar', 'open')
  } else if (!elemToFocus.hasAttribute('data-focus-inmodal')) {
    document.querySelector('.app-wrapper').setAttribute('data-sidebar', 'closed')
  }
  lastFocused = elemToFocus
  console.log(`FOCUS: ${elem.id} add focus to ${elemToFocus.id}`)
  elemToFocus.classList.add('focus')
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('app:focusChanged', { detail: elemToFocus }))
}

function findParentFocusGroup(elem) {
  if (elem.hasAttribute('data-focusgroup')) {
    return elem
  }

  const parent = elem.parentNode
  if (parent && parent.nodeType !== 9) return findParentFocusGroup(parent)
}
```

I notice if this function is called in fast succession, I can get the following output in console:

```
FOCUS: history0
FOCUS: history0 removing focus from vodBannerProgram
FOCUS: vodBannerProgram
FOCUS: vodBannerProgram add focus to vodBannerProgram
FOCUS: history0 add focus to history0
```

Notice, it seems like this function is called for `history0` first then `vodBannerProgram`. But it seems like it executed halfway for `history0` then proceeded to `vodBannerProgram` then back again? `forEach` are synchronous correct?

Comment: I guess that `store.dispatch` is async

Comment: @h1b9b seems like I should move the `store.dispatch` to the end, but even if its async, should the code below execute after anyways?

Comment: Is the prints order always this way (when you do the same actions)? if so it's not race condition and maybe `setFocusElem` case the prints in the middle

Comment: @RoyShmuli I need to do it fast enough for it to get this result, so it sounds like a race condition?

Comment: 1. On focus history0, does it will print history0 and vodBannerProgram?
2. If so, When you focus history0, is it print vodBannerProgram somtimes at the end or it always in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

There is no race condition without async. You don't display enough code to find it (if this is the case). Check the following code:

1. `setFocusElem`
2. `store.dispatch`

Comment: Hmm ... these are redux specific ... let me try removing that. But even if these are async, it would mean the below code should run immediately after anyways? So I should not be getting this interleaving?

Comment: @JiewMeng `store.dispatch` is sync. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276291/is-store-dispatch-in-redux-synchronous-or-asynchronous