# React + Redux. Route after dispatch [Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, browser-history, react-router-dom

in my React App, after dispatching an action I want to rout to home page.

index.js

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

my component that I want to rout from.

```
class GameElements extends Component {
  cancel = () => {const { history, cancelGame: cancelGameAlt } = this.props;
    cancelGameAlt().then(() => history.push("/HomePage"));
  };

  render() {return( /*button that calls cancel*/);}

GameElements.propTypes = {
history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }).isRequired}
```

and the cancelGame action is defined as

```
export const cancelGame = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: types.PLAYER_CANCELS_GAME });
};
```

the action is dispatched and the state at store changes, but I at this line; `cancelGameAlt().then(() => history.push("/HomePage"));`get an error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

before clicking when page renders I get `Failed prop type: The prop`history`is marked as required in`GameElements`, but its value is`undefined`.`
but I read that `react-router 4` use the history as a prop of your component.

How should I route after calling an action?

Comment: Hint: What does the `cancelGame` do? Look at what it returns. It should be a `Promise` for this to work.

Comment: At which line the error occurs

Comment: What are you trying to do ? As @HardikModha mentioned,  you didn't include the code that is causing the problem . Edit your question and include `cancelGameAlt()`

Comment: Edited the Post

Comment: dispatch is synchronous. It doesn't return a `Promise`. For more info see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276291/is-store-dispatch-in-redux-synchronous-or-asynchronous

Comment: @HardikModha Thanks, but I am using Thunk

Comment: How should I make it work then

Comment: @Harikrishnan Edited The Post

Comment: I think what you want is `types.PLAYER_CANCELS_GAME` => reducer sets the `isCancelled` to true and if the value is set to true you navigate to the `HomePage`. So you need to check for that `isCancelled` flag inside your component. Are there any network requests involved when you do dispatch `PLAYER_CANCELS_GAME`?

Comment: @HardikModha I just realised another warning when page renders, 'history' is undefined.