# Can we access the changed reducer state in react app synchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have dispatched an action which doesn't contain any asynchronous code such as ajax call or anything which changes the reducer state. Can I access the changed reducer state in the very next line in the react app?

**React APP**

```
actions.setName('Test'); //this sets the name in state of reducer to Test
//Can I access the name in the next line
const name = this.props.name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Redux store's state itself is immediately updated, because dispatching is synchronous.  However, React's re-rendering is almost always asynchronous, so no, updates to props are *not* available immediately after an action was dispatched.

Answer (score 1):

```
let response = await this.props.appAction.processList(token, userName);
prodArray = this.props.processList;
```

This is my example code and it works. Maybe it can help you. await keyword works for me.

Comment: Here you are explicitly making the response line of code synchronous by using await. But what I am asking conceptually is- would the reducer state change and the new state be available on reaching the next line without any of these promises/await

Comment: Yes it should as redux functioning is synchronous. Here my appAction.processList is a network request that's why there is the need of await.

Comment: The dispatch function is not synchronous.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43276291/is-store-dispatch-in-redux-synchronous-or-asynchronous

Maybe this helps you to understand

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that we cannot have the state updated immediately and available as props in the next line.

The only way you get the updated state is when component re-renders. You cannot expect the next line to have the latest state at any time.

Look into this discussion for further understanding on how to go about solving this issue.

[Click for the discussion thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524855/how-to-trigger-off-callback-after-updating-state-in-redux)