# How to update component state on redux state change?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Since I have a component with forms, I need the forms to be connected to the component state. The initial data comes from Redux so try to initialize and update the component by setting the state with the props:

```
componentWillMount = () => {
  this.setState({
    language: this.props.language || 'en'
  })
}
```

`language` is a connected prop and I checked that it is updated in the store.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  language: state.language
})
```

I also tried to use `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentWillUpdate` but it doesn't work. I get the initial state, and even though the store and the connected props change, the component's state doesn't update.

```
{this.props.language} // updates
{this.state.language} // doesn't change
```

What is the correct way to manage forms from Redux data?

---

The `render` part:

```
render () {
  const {classes, theme, web} = this.props

  const language = (
    <CardContent>
      <Typography type="headline">
        Language
      </Typography>
      <Divider/>
      <form className={classes.container} autoComplete="off">
        <FormControl fullWidth margin="normal">
          <InputLabel htmlFor="language">Select Block</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={this.state.language} // <==================== language
            onChange={this.handleLanguaheChange}
            input={<Input id="language"/>}
          >
            <MenuItem value={'en'}>English</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'he'}>עברית</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    </CardContent>
  )
  ...

  return (
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={theme.spacing.unit * 3}
        justify={'space-between'}
        className={classes.gridWrap}
      >
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <Card className={classes.card}>
            {language}
          </Card>
...
```

Comment: are you setting state in componentWillReceiveProps. Also calling setState synchronously in componentWillMount won't trigger extra rendering

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I tried `componentWillMount `, `componentWillUpdate ` and `componentWillReceiveProps ` but none of them worked

Comment: Can you add the relevant code of your componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri it is the exact same code as the one I pasted with `componentWillMount `

Comment: Typo on handler: ` onChange={this.handleLanguaheChange} `... Edit mode won't allow me to fix unless I edit a further 5 characters 

Comment: `return new Promise.resolve()`, this solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524855/how-to-trigger-off-callback-after-updating-state-in-redux

Answer (score 3):

First, you are using an arrow function for componentWillMount. Rule of thumb is, do not use arrow functions for life-cycle hooks(componentWillMount, shouldComponentUpdate, ...etc). It's usual to setState in componentWillMount hook. But never set state in componentDidMount.
please try to re-write it as,

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props)
 this.state = {
  language: 'en',
 }
}
componentWillMount() {
 const { language } = this.props
 if (language) this.setState(prevState => ({ language: prevState.language = language }))
}
```

in some exceptional cases, such as i wrote two classes in a single .js file(like i said, some exceptions) and i couldn't be able to modify it from componentWillMount as expected(later noted, the props are modified by the child class). 
in such cases, you can override it in render

```
render() {
 const { language } = this.props
 if (language) this.setState(prevState => ({ language: prevState.language = language }))
```

Comment: **It's usual to setState in componentWillMount hook. But never set state in componentDidMount.**
Never do that. You're not supposed to setState for unmounted component, it may cause memory loss. And there's no issue in setting state in ComponentDidMount.

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this with React Hooks:

1. Track previous value with `useRef()`
2. Compare with previous value and **conditionally** update the local component state

The posted example didn't really make sense to me so here is the problem I faced:

I have a form with component state that I needed to clear out when the redux state changed.

[image]

To accomplish this my component looks like this:

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
const CreateCase = () => {

  //redux state
  const accounts = useSelector(state => state.accounts);

  //component state
  const [productId, setProductId] = useState(undefined);

  const prevAccountRef = useRef<string>();
  useEffect(() => {
    //compare current with previous account and clear productId if changed
    if (account.id != prevAccountRef.current) {
      setProductId(undefined);
    }
    //set previous account for next render
    prevAccountRef.current = account.id;
  });

  //... render
}
```

It's very important that you only run `setState` inside of `useEffect` conditionally.

Answer (score 1):

> even though the store and the connected props change, the component's state doesn't update

The way you have it written, the state won't update unless you explicitly update it using `setState()` (most likely in the `componentWillReceiveProps()` method).

When you use `mapStateToProps()` with the Redux `connect()` HOC, you are mapping your Redux state to your component through its **props**, so in your case `this.props.language` will update when the Redux stored updates.

Comment: Yes, so I thought that once the props will update, it will trigger `componentWillReceiveProps` and thus update the state. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, what it is the purpose of the component's `state` (updated with `this.setState`) when `react-redux` maps the Redux's `state` to the `props` and not to the component's `state`? When do we use component's `state` then?

Comment: @tonix I believe you want to use props to change state externally, and state to change state internally (in relation to the component).

Comment: @Kin Like changing something which relates exclusively to the component and not the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

[`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentWillReceiveProps) will be called only when your component re-rendered.

Initially when component first time mounting, it not going to triggered.

You can not call `setState` inside [`componentwillupdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate).

In order to initialise the initial state of component from redux store,you should use `constructor`.

```
    constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
        language: this.props.language || 'en'
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanx, what is the difference between using `constructor` and `componentwillMount/reciveProps` in this case?

Comment: Please share your render part where you are using it

Comment: @ilyo `this.state.language ` is still there. You need to use `this.props.language ` after constructor changes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160717/discussion-between-riyaj-khan-and-ilyo).

Comment: I am confused, the whole point of setting the state is so (1) I can use it with forms (2) I will have a fallback value until the server populates the redux store

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies, but I ran into a similar problem recently and my case was due to the fact that calling this.setState does not guarantee an *instant* update to state; it only says that the state change will be effected eventually.

From the react-component documentation:

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
>   update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
>   does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

If you need to make some "instant" changes to state or things that depend on state, then there's that callback on setState() that you can use to lock things in place. The callback is what worked for me.