# Sending and Retrieving user ID from Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase.auth() to authenticate a login with Google Firebase then I retrieve the UID and send it to my Redux Store. The UID is not being sent to the store unless I navigate to the next page then return to the login page. It seems my order of operations is off, how can I get the UID in my Redux store without haveing to re-login/ refresh the page.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: ''
        }
    }

id (value) {
        this.props.id(value);
    }
```

```
handleLogin = (load) => {

        const { email, password } = this.state

        Firebase.auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(async cred => {
                return db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
                    test: 'test'
                })
            })
            .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddProfiles'))

            .catch(error => console.log(error))
        

        const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        
        const userId = currentUser["uid"];
       
        this.setState({
            id: userId
        })
        this.props.id(this.state.id);
    }
```

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.signupbutton}>
      <Button
           color='white'
           title="Log in"
           onPress={(payload) => this.handleLogin()}
       />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        counter: state.counter,
        value: state.id
    };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        id: (value) => dispatch({ type: 'id', payload: value })
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the code starting with the line `const currentUser` is running *before* the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` completes, since `signInWithEmailAndPassword` is an *asynchronous* function. The reason that it works on refresh is at that point, `firebase.auth().currentUser` has a value, so

You can move your code inside the `then` block so that it runs only when the function is complete. It'll look something like this (untested, because I don't have the rest of your code):

```
handleLogin = (load) => {

        const { email, password } = this.state

        Firebase.auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(async cred => {
                this.setState({
                 id: cred.user.uid
                })
                this.props.id(cred.user.id);
                return db.collection('users').doc(cred.user.uid).set({
                    test: 'test'
                })
            })
            .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('AddProfiles'))

            .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Note that `setState` is *also* asynchronous, so calling `this.props.id(this.state.id);` right after `setState` is likely to fail on the first run.

Although the above should fix the immediate issue, I'd suggest `onAuthStateChanged`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

This way, you can do your sign in and set the Redux state based on its value *or* run the same code to set the Redux value when the user just returns to a page. It'll probably lead to a more robust situation than tying everything to `signInWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure as to how to run these operations in the correct order.  I moved my code inside the .then block but now I am returning undefined from my state upon running my code for the first time. I think I should use onAuthStateChanged as well.

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to manage when you set the `id` part of your state. I think `onAuthStateChanged` is the way to go, but of course, that won't be available on first render, either (since it's async), so you'll have to account for what happens before there's a value available.

Comment: If this answered your initial question, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: It answered the order of operations question but I am still not having access to the uid on the first iteration of rendering the page.

Comment: Previously I would return no value from the store upon first auth and render, now upon first auth and render I am receiving undefined

Comment: On first render, you will not have access to the uid, unless it's stored in a rehydrated redux state. In your previous example, it looks like `state.id` should have been `''` on first render. And it should be the same on mine, right? Because `setState` doesn't get called until `signInWithEmailAndPassword` completes

Comment: is there a way to wait for the uid to be sent to the store then access it before navigating to the next page?

Comment: What do you mean "then access it"? To do what? I can probably give an example if I know what should be going on.

Comment: so on the next pages on my app I render data stored under that particular uid who is logged in. The data in the firestore database wont render on the consecutive pages unless i log in then go back to the log in page and log in again for a second time. Then I am able to access the data stored in the database under that particular uid.

Comment: I'd have to see a [mre]. Are you saying that even with this code, on the subsequent page (`AddProfiles`), you're not seeing the `uid` stored in redux?

Comment: Yes prior to the changes mentioned it was storing it in redux store after the second render, now it is returning undefined  no matter how many log in attempts I make.

Comment: You'll have to use a callback or something akin to it to make sure that the navigation only happens once it's stored. I'm not a heavy redux user, so it's not something I'm immediately familiar with. May want to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39524855/how-to-trigger-off-callback-after-updating-state-in-redux

Comment: ok I will check it out! seems like that is the solution I am looking for. Essentially waiting for the storage of the uid before navigation.